# Among Cadence Virtuoso Calculator functions, is there a function that returns the y value when given an x value?

Tags: cadence

Among Cadence Virtuoso Calculator functions, is there a function that returns the y value when given an x value?

I know the "cross" function can return the x value when given a y value. But what I need is the opposite - given x, return y.

Could anyone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try the value() function. Maybe yval() is also useful. Just read the manual here: http://home.engineering.iastate.edu/~hmeng/EE501lab/TAHelp/wavescanug.pdf the same manual is available from within the calculator.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks a lot. The function "value" works though the function "yval" is not available in my Cadence version.

Comment: I think you should use the value function
"value(y x)" returns the y in the given x